# replace regex string with parameter / token

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this code snippet of a code base I am supposed to maintain.

```
String number = "1";
String value = "test";
String output = "";

output = value.replaceAll("\\Q{#}", number);
```

The value of `output` stays as "test" and I can only guess what this code is supposed to do: the value of `number`should be appended to whatever is in value. Maybe something like this: `test1` or replace the value with the number entirely.

I found out that `\\Q` is the regex option to quote everything until `\\E` but there is no `\\E`. Anyway it is not doing anything at all and I am wondering if I oversee something?

Comment: The regex just matches a literal `{#}`. If your `value` is `test{#}`, the `{#}` will get replaced with the number. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/Zizftn). `\\E` just stops quoting, if it is missing, the whole pattern will get quoted, that's all.

Comment: AFAIK `#` is no special character in regex so assuming Java regex understands `\Q` it would look for the literal string `{#}` which is not present in `value`. Besides that your guess is wrong: `replaceAll` replaces the match with `number` - if you want to append something at the end you'd need match the end of the input, e.g. just using the expression `$`.

Comment: I can't see a question in the post. What are you looking for?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is exactly what I needed. An explanation what this thing exactly does because my guess was totally wrong. I thought # would be a special character, in this case a token or something similar which would get replaced. Thanks. If you put your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct. @@Thomas thanks for clarifying and the explanation.

Comment: That makes the question a dupe of [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Comment: I am not sure because I read that page but could not find information in regard to why my assumptions were wrong and nothing in regard to `{#}`. But if you think it is a duplicate then I am happy if you mark it as such or I just delete my question.

Comment: Ok, I could not find exact info there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex just matches a literal `{#}`. It is true that after `\Q` the pattern is considered to have literal symbols (all the symbols after `\Q` get "quoted" or "escaped"), and `\E` stops this escaping/quoting, and if it is missing, the whole pattern will get quoted/escaped.

If your *value* variable holds `test{#}` value, the `{#}` will get replaced with the number.

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/Zizftn):

```
String number = "1";
String value = "test{#}";
String output = "";
output = value.replaceAll("\\Q{#}", number);
System.out.println(output); // => test1
```

Note that without `\Q`, your regex (`{#}`) would throw a `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition` error because Java regex engine is not "smart" enough to disambiguate the braces (PCRE, JS, .NET can easily guess that since there is no number inside, it is not a limiting/bound quantifier).